# DropDownListFor issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a method which returns list items. Problem occurs, when i try to populate the DropDownList with this items. I get a null exception everytime. Where's the catch?

Method:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetItems()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();

        list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Ptuj", Value = "1" });
        list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Celje", Value = "2" });
        list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Laško", Value = "3" });
        list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Maribor", Value = "4" });
        list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Ljubljana", Value = "5" });
        list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "N/A", Value = "6" });


        foreach (SelectListItem item in list)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
```

View:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PlaceOfBirth)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PlaceOfBirth, //Exception thrown in this line
        Model.GetItems())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would changed that List to a SelectList. You are already using SelectListItems, so you may as well go the whole hog and use a SelectList.

Then, just return the SelectList. You can leave the signature return type as an IEnumerable,  as the SelectList class implements that interface (well, it's parent does, anyway).

Let me elaborate with an example. Here is a model:

```
public class AModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> places { get; set; }
    public int SelectedValue { get; set; }
}
```

Here is an Index action method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

    AModel model = new AModel{ places = GetItems(), SelectedValue = 0 };

    return View(model);
}
```

And here is your new GetItems method:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetItems()
{
    List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();

    list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Ptuj", Value = "1" });
    list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Celje", Value = "2" });
    list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Laško", Value = "3" });
    list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Maribor", Value = "4" });
    list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Ljubljana", Value = "5" });
    list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "N/A", Value = "6" });

    SelectList thelist = new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text");

    return thelist;
}
```

See how you go with that.

**Edit (add view)**:

```
  @model AModel

  @{
      ViewBag.Title = "Index";
  }

  <h2>Example</h2>

  Here are the places: @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedValue, (SelectList)Model.Places, "Select a place")
```

Comment: how would the code in View look like? To show the DropDownlist.

Comment: @cvenko I edited my answer to include the razor view, which should be called Index.cshtml and placed inside a folder called Home inside the Views folder in your solution. I also changed the SelectedValue to 0, to display the default text.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are calling `GetItems` method of your viewmodel/model in the view. to get the items. Oh No ! Don't do that.

Add a collection property to your viewmodel for the dropdown. Viewmodel is just ***POCO***. No methods on that.

```
public class SignUpVM
{
   public string Name{ set;get;}
   public List<SelectListItem> Cities{ set;get;}
   public int PlaceOfBirth {set;get;}
}
```

Now in your **GET** action method ,create an object of this viewmodel and fill the `Cities` collection property and return that to the view.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
 var vm=new SignUpVM();
 vm.Cities=GetCities();
 return View(vm);
}
```

Assuming `GetCities` method returns a List of `SelectListItem` for the cities.

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetCities()
{
  List<SelectListItem> cityList=new List<SelectListItem>();
  cityList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Ptuj", Value = "1" });
  cityList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Celje", Value = "2" });
  return cityList;
}
```

Now in our view, which is strongly typed to `SignUpVM`

```
@model SignUpVM
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.PlaceOfBirth,
                           new SelectList(Model.Cities,"Value","Text"),"select")
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

When you submit the form you will get the selected item's id in the `PlaceOfBirth` property.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(SignUpVM model)
{
  int placeOfBirthId=model.PlaceOfBirth;
  // TO DO : Save and redirect.
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting null exception in the same line. Could it be because "Index" page is displayed first, when running application? Because i think, that the list is empty until i click Submit. And if i change first page to "Information" in project properties, I get 404 error.

Comment: are you seeing the error in your GET action method or POST? is dropdown rendering some items ?

Comment: @cvenko there was typos in my form markup.i corrected it. try the updated answer.

Comment: I get the error in "Index" View in line: `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PlaceOfBirth,
 new SelectList(Model.Cities,"Value","Text"),"select")`

Comment: @cvenko and we are returning the viewmodel with cities in `Create` action. not `Index`